# Is there any public place to watch the Olympic games in Singapore?

Tags: singapore, olympics

I just arrived at Singapore, but it's a country where people seemingly don't care much about the Olympics.

However, I want to watch the games in public places. In Tokyo, you can watch the games at electronics store where it is not uncommon that many people on a lunch break gather there to cheer for the games.

Is it possible to watch the games at public places in Singapore, possibly for free? I definitely don't want to watch it at hotel.

Comment: Singapore being (currently) 11 hours ahead of Rio, most of the events will take place overnight there.

Comment: @pnuts Hmm... I don't like such too noisy environment. Plus, I don't drink alcohol.

Comment: The reason for a downvote?

Comment: @Blaszard any chance you did find a place and would want to throw in an answer?

Comment: @mts Unfortunately, no. And the Olympic is already done...

Comment: So is it possible that the answer is actually "no"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Olympic games are over and any answers are unlikely to help future visitors

Comment: Well the Olympics are going to happen again...

Comment: Yeah but they're not guaranteed to be shown at the same spot.